Compiling/ _not-found... in Next.js GET /socket.io?X_LOCAL_SECURITY_COOKIE=&EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1719561373697-135 404
When I ran the command 'npm run dev' and Next.js start to compiling, I got the error in the image:

I don't know what error it is or how to fix it. However, Next.js still applies the changes when I Ctrl + S, but it us kind of annoying when it  always pop-up the message.
I have tried to create a new project with next.js, but it still happens.

I figured out the error, just uninstalled the GeForce Experience from Nvidia and everything worked fine. It seemed that the error came from the Nvidia's services.

+1 Thanks! I can't believe I had the same issue. GeForce Experience broke after a system restore and was causing this problem for me. Fixed after a re-install.

I had the same problem, updating GeForce Experience helped me, so if anyone else has a similar problem, check if there are any updates available.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

i just update the GeForce Experience driver and works
